# jquery scroll down button enhancement

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to to scroll down the browser by a certain predefined height every time I click on "go down" button.

http://jsfiddle.net/uw1hdkaf/

> ```
> var scrolled=0;    
> $(document).ready(function(){                
>     $("#downClick").on("click" ,function(){
>       scrolled=scrolled+500;
>
>       $("html, body").animate({
>               scrollTop:  scrolled
>          });  
>     });
>
> });
> ```

It seems working fine, but I realized when it reaches the bottom of the page, if I drag the browser's side scroll bar all the way to the top and click the button again, it will scroll all the way down to the bottom. I need to refresh the page in order to make it work again. I wonder ....

1) How to enhance the code so that the "go down" button's scrolling will be consistent and stable no matter where I drag the scroll bar to.

2) When reaching near bottom of the page (eg.100px), it will add a class, e.g "bottom" to the button for styling.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the last value of `scrolled` simply calculate the `.scrollTop()` value of the "body" element, which will tell you how far down the page you are, and add 500 to that amount.

```
var scrolled;    
$(document).ready(function(){                
    $("#downClick").on("click" ,function(){
      scrolled= $("body").scrollTop()+500;

      $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop:  scrolled
         });  
    });

});
```

To calculate when we're at the bottom we also need to take into account the height of the `window`, and if your scrollTop value plus the window height is greater than or equal to the height of the body then we can deduce that you're at the bottom:

```
var documentHeight = $("body").height(),
    windowHeight, scrolled;

$(document).ready(function(){                
    $("#downClick").on("click" ,function(){
      scrolled= $("body").scrollTop() + 500;
      windowHeight = $(window).height();
      $(this).toggleClass("bottom", scrolled + windowHeight >= documentHeight);

      $("html, body").animate({
              scrollTop:  scrolled
         });  
    });

});
```

Note that I only calculate the body size once, but the window size each time. I'm assuming that whilst users may change their browser width, that the document itself won't grow / shrink in size, because there's a cost associated with calculating the height.

**[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uw1hdkaf/2/)**

Comment: `scrolled= $("body").scrollTop() + 500;` have to be `scrolled= $("html, body").scrollTop() + 500;` if you put some more `<p>`-tags in your fiddle it only works on the first click.

Comment: It depends on where you're running this, if in an iFrame "body" will suffice, otherwise you should use "html" AFAIK

Comment: Yeah but i think there is no disadvantage to play safe by using ``('html, body')``. Right?

Comment: Well it wasn't working for me in JSFiddle, so it's a little annoying!

Comment: Yeah, I added ('html, body') as @DerVampyr suggested and it works well. But one thing doesn't work well now is when I move the scroll bar to the top again or away from the bottom of the page, the "bottom" class still remain attached. Anyway to improve the code so that when it reaches the bottom of the page, it adds the class "bottom" and when it is away from the bottom, the class will be removed automatically which it serves it's purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Just add another event on scroll to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

Try this

`scrollTop:   $("html, body").scrollTop() + 500`

It will check the scrollTop value and add 500 to it and doesn´t care on which scroll position you are.